# How to set the content type application/json and application/xml using Swashbuckle in swagger UI

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Hi I am using Swashbuckle
I want to set content type "application/json and application/xml" for request and response payload. Can anyone help me how can I set content Type according to my preferences.
I have tried this code it is working for request bur not for response.
[HttpPost]

```
    [Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [SwaggerResponse(200,null,typeof(Logs))]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, null, typeof(Logs))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure content type for response, you can use a filters:

```
public class SwaggerMediaTypesOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var key in operation.Responses.Keys)
        {
            FilterMediaTypes(operation.Responses[key].Content);
        }

        if (operation.RequestBody?.Content != null)
        {
            FilterMediaTypes(operation.RequestBody.Content);
        }
    }

    private static void FilterMediaTypes(IDictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType> apiMediaTypes)
    {
        if (apiMediaTypes.TryGetValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, out OpenApiMediaType applicationJson))
        {
            apiMediaTypes.Clear();
            apiMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, applicationJson);
            apiMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml, applicationJson);
        }
    }
}
```

Then,

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(cfg =>
{
  cfg.OperationFilter<SwaggerMediaTypesOperationFilter>();
  ...
};
```